# Cannot access the responseBody in the retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

```
Cannot access class 'okhttp3.ResponseBody'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

This is my function:

```
fun parseError(httpException: HttpException) {
    val errorBody = httpException.response()?.errorBody()
}
```

These are the dependencies that I have included

```
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.15.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")
```

This is the image as you can see there is a error below the `errorBody()`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Answer;

I found that there is a problem in version 2.9.0 of this retrofit. It will be fixed after updating to version 2.8.2.

**version.properties file**

`version.retrofit2=2.8.2`

---

You can use it by doing 2.8.2.

Old Answer;

I think your project is multi module. Can you try the "api" instead of "implementation"?

I'm making this comment because I can't see more details.

> The reason it cannot find related dependencies is that the dependency
> as reference of our project exposes third-party dependency onto its
> API surfaces.

Comment: Yes, the project is multi-module I have a presentation, domain, and data modules.

Comment: Hi,  you can checkout the code here https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyTasky/tree/develop

Comment: thanks, down grading to version 2.8.2 has seemed to fixed my issue. However, I am just wondering what steps you took to come to that solution?

Comment: Actually, I tried many ways. Instead of implementation an api is given. I disabled okhttp manually. I tried it in an empty project. I downgraded the Kotlin version. But when you can't get results. I analyzed the Retrofit versions. I was successful when I updated it to the most recent stable version.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one dependency which has OkHttp3.ResponseBody class

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{latest_version}'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I have tried to add that dependency but still getting the same issue. I have updated my question wtih those depenencies.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Retrofit [depends on version 3.14.9](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/8f788fd3d26cf76d4749eb9df049090de434da66/gradle/libs.versions.toml#L17C1-L17C18) of OkHttp, but you are trying to force a newer version, specifically 4.11.0. Please note that in version 4.*, all classes in the OkHttp library [were migrated to Kotlin](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/), and this migration might be the cause of the error you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")`. Retrofit2 already have the OkHttp client depend as `api`.